# I want no launch image but Apple is forcing me to have one

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

The purpose of launch images is to fake that the app is starting to give time to the app to fully load but I have this app of mine that is so fast to load that the launch image just is visible for less than 0.1 seconds. I have tested the app without the launch image and it loads fast than with a launch image.

When I submit the app to Apple without the launch image it fails validation.

This is ridiculous. Is there a way to solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to use a launch image that looks like the first screen of your app with text removed, so it looks like a blank slate of your interface. Once your app starts rendering, it will be obvious to the user that it's reached that point.

Many times games will have a splash screen, especially since they sometimes load resources during that time. So those will usually either have a launch image that is their splash screen, where once rendering it starts it makes some animation occur, or they will sometimes start with a black launch image because the logo/splash will fade in.

As you said, the app fails validation without the launch image. Also when Apple first came out with the iPhone 5, the way you added support for the iPhone 5 screen size was by adding a launch image at that size. So in that case Apple is actually using the presence of the launch image to determine if you support the screen size or not. In other words, you need launch images, and it does help with the user experience, even if it is only visible for a split second.

Comment: Correct - use a launch image that looks like the first screen of your app, but without content. Apple's Human Interface Guidelines has some example launch images from some of their apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html (note, they should probably be very simple and boring!)

Comment: @JamesFrost, true, they're just there to give the illusion that your app has launched faster, and make everything seem smoother. It's not intended to be the "splash screen" that a lot of people want to use it for (especially those annoying things I call "clients"...)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to solve it - you must have a launch image.

You *could* use a launch image that looks a lot like your first page, so it doesn't look so jarring when it briefly flashes up.

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked when you don't have a launch image for a debug build iOS uses a default image.  If I remember right it is black.  So you could create an all black image and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Ive personally never used a launch image and have gotten all of my apps approved. Maybe you're failing validation because of something else?

Comment: nope. The message is clear when the validation fails.

Comment: I thought Apple changed their validator to require launch images in the last year, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: When you create an Xcode project, it creates black launch images by default. So maybe you've just never noticed that they're there, but it does require them.

Answer (score -1):

you do not need a launch image. This is not causing you to fail validation